# Send email from one of many accounts in Django

Tags: python, django, email

Is it possible to configure Django to send email *from* one of multiple addresses, so that I can select whether the email will be sent from `support@mydomain.com`, `noreply@mydomain.com`, etc?

It seems that specifying an address in `django.core.mail.send_mail` is useless, as `EMAIL_*` variables in settings.py are used for sending an email, and I don't know how to specify multiple email addresses.

Comment: Did you read [send_mail documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#send-mail)?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `django-mailer` for this purpose. Install django-mailer with

```
pip install django-mailer
```

Github repository available [here](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer). Also [This link](https://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/django-django-mailer-multi-account-setup-plus-throttling/) provides an easy way to switch between accounts.